# Не получается заливка на GitHub

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-key

В общем все у меня работало но во время атаки на гит я подумал что проблема у меня и начал дергаться и вводить команды найденные в гугле по имени ошибки, не очень вдаваясь что они значат. И получил проблему:
Ничего не могу залить... Помогите поправить. Не хочется все сносить и переустанавливать гит.

```
Mac-mini-Pavel:junior pavel$ git push origin master
ssh: connect to host example.com port 1234: No route to host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: вы сменили remote с названием origin, вместо которого надо указать нужный вида git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> host example.com port 1234

Вы пытаетесь соединиться с сервером example.com через порт 1234. Разумеется, это был просто пример, вы поняли его буквально. "example.com" используется, когда нужно заполнить место для URL каким-то понятным примером.

Похоже, вы перенастроили адрес удаленного репозитория. Проверим:

```
git remote -v
origin  <что тут написано?> (fetch)
origin  <и тут> (push)
```

Настроим обратно. Найдите свой проект на гитхабе, скопируйте оттуда адрес. Как верно заметил Etki, адрес имеет вид `git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git`. Теперь его нужно перенастроить. Это нужно делать в той папке, где находится ваш проект.

```
cd /путь/к/вашему/проекту/
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git
```

Только не поймите строку выше буквально! На месте `<user>` и `<repo>` должно быть имя вашего аккаунта на гитхабе и имя проекта.

Comment: Да подумал и я ужасно раскаиваюсь, что не обратил внимания на эти мысли. Без всякой иронии. ((( Теперь у меня другая ошибка

Comment: Mac-mini-Pavel:junior pavel$ git push origin master
To git@github.com:triodjangopiter/junior.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:triodjangopiter/junior.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: а при попытки синхронизации вот так

Comment: Mac-mini-Pavel:junior pavel$ git fetch
Mac-mini-Pavel:junior pavel$ git rebase
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
See git-rebase(1) for details.

    git rebase <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

Comment: А при введении git remote -v получается Mac-mini-Pavel:junior pavel$ git remote -v
origin git@github.com:triodjangopiter/junior.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:triodjangopiter/junior.git (push) тоесть часть проблемы решилась но похоже это не все что я сломал(((

Comment: @Павел а вот про это стоит уже новый вопрос задать. )

Comment: @Павел т.е. там тоже понятно, в чём дело, но тут принято посвящать один вопрос одной проблеме. )

Comment: Хорошо спасибо буду знать. Сейчас новый создам.